# Who stole the flying car in Hogwarts?

Tags: logical-deduction, liars

During a trial in a Hogwarts court, Ron claimed that the Flying Ford Anglia car was stolen by Hermione.

Then Hermione and Harry gave testimonies which, for some reason, were not recorded. Later on in the trial it was found that the car was stolen by one of these three defendants, and moreover, only the guilty one gave true testimony.

> Who stole the car?

Comment: I'm flagging this for migration to [scifi.se] ;-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor No, literature :P

Comment: @thecoder16 No, History.

Comment: Wait, obviously law.se

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Only the guilty one gave true testimony.**

There are 2 options for being guilty and giving true testimony:

1. > Declaring yourself guilty
2. > Declaring someone else not guilty

Ron declares someone guilty different than himself (1), which means

> he's lying.

> If Ron lies, he can't be the guilty one, so he's innocent.

> If Ron lies, what he says is false. So Hermione is innocent as well.

> If Ron and Hermione are innocent, Harry is guilty (and he'll admit it).

Answer (score 36):

> If Ron was guilty, he would be telling the truth, which cannot be the case since he claimed Hermione stole the car. So Ron is lying, which results Hermione did not stole the car.

This results

> Harry stole the car whatever Hermione’s testimony is.

Comment: I think Hermione can't give any random testimony like "Harry stole the car". Am I wrong?

Comment: @Simba I said "whatever Hermione's testimony is", I did not tell any random testimony. It means we dont need that testimony to get the result.

Comment: This is true, but there's a plot hole. Only harry could have stolen the car, but it means Hermione's testimony also had to be false, or more likely mistaken. She couldn't simply have said "I did not!" but something like "You probably stole it yourself, Ron!"

Comment: Actually, she could have said either
- "I'm guilty"
- "You're guilty, Ron"
- "Harry is innocent".
So, "whatever Hermione's testimony is", out of these three-like.

Comment: @BorjaVidalArqué if he said something like that, the given information would be wrong.

Comment: Exactly @Oray. She (Hermione) would be wrong. In case she said something right, she would be the guilty one, and we've prooved that's not possible.

Answer (score 8):

Given:

> - Only the guilty gave the true testimony
>  
>
>  - Ron says Hermione is guilty
>  
>
>  - Harry and Hermione also gave their testimonies

Now:

> Since Ron testified that Hermione is guilty, he is definitely
>  lying, since he isn't guilty (as only the guilty party testified truthfully).
>  Since Ron says Hermione stole it, considering the fact that he is
>  lying (again, because only the guilty party spoke the truth) Hermione isn't
>  the thief either. So the thief has to be **Harry**, by my logic.

Answer (score -2):

We can say that:

> Ron is guilty.

Because:

> The question does not say the guilty one gave *entirely* true testimony.  Ron is the only one we can *confirm* gave true testimony:  *Ron claimed that the Flying Ford Anglia car was stolen*

Therefore:

> We can infer that Ron was guilty, regardless of the other details.

Comment: a quality answer should not rely on a cheap play on word like that